# Next.js localStorage not defined even using useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I know, there is a lot of similar questions although I could not find a solution to my problem. It is the first time I am using Next.js and TypeScrypt.

I am simulating a login with [REQRES](https://reqres.in/) storing the token in the localStorage as shown below:

```
import {
  FormControl,
  FormLabel,
  Input,
  Heading,
  Flex,
  Button,
  useToast,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useState } from 'react';

import LStorage from '../utils/localStorage/index';

const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const handleEmail = (e: any) => setEmail(e.target.value);
  const handlePassword = (e: any) => setPassword(e.target.value);
  const router = useRouter();
  const toast = useToast();

  const success = () => toast({
    title: 'Login Successfull',
    description: 'You will be redirected now.',
    status: 'success',
    duration: 1200,
    isClosable: true,
  });

  const failure = (error: string) => toast({
    title: 'Login unsuccessfull',
    description: error,
    status: 'error',
    duration: 3000,
    isClosable: true,
  });

  const login = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('/api', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email,
        password,
      }),
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
    });
    const json = await res.json();
    console.log(json);
    if (json.error) {
      failure(json.error);
      setEmail('');
      setPassword('');
    } else {
      LStorage.set('userToken', json.token);
      LStorage.set('userInfo', email);
      success();
      setTimeout(() => {
        router.push('/users');
      }, 1500);
    }
  };

  return (<div>
    <Flex justifyContent="center">
      <Heading my="5">Login</Heading>
    </Flex>
    <FormControl>
      <FormLabel htmlFor="email">Email:</FormLabel>
      <Input id="email" type="email" onChange={handleEmail} value={email}/>
      <FormLabel htmlFor="password">Password:</FormLabel>
      <Input id="password" type="password" onChange={handlePassword} value={password}/>
    </FormControl>
    <br />
    <Button onClick={login}>Login</Button>
  </div>);
};

export default Login;
```

which seem to work fine. Although when trying to get the userInfo from localStorage at the _app.tsx component I get the localStorage not defined, looking for the error I found out the solution below inside the useEffect.

```
import '../styles/globals.sass';
import { ChakraProvider } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import NavBar from '../components/NavBar';
import MainLayout from '../layouts/mainLayout';
import theme from '../styles/theme';
import LStorage from '../utils/localStorage/index';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const logout = () => {
    LStorage.remove('userToken');
    LStorage.remove('userInfo');
    setUserInfo(null);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      if (LStorage.get('userInfo')) {
        setUserInfo(LStorage.get('userInfo'));
      }
    }
    console.log('i am here');
  }, []);

  return (
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
      <NavBar user={userInfo} logout={logout} />
      <MainLayout>
        <Component {...pageProps}/>
      </MainLayout>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

I understood that the first run will be on the server-side and that is why I got the error, nevertheless, using the useEffect should fix it. The thing is the useEffect does not even run unless I refresh the page... **What am I missing??!??**

The Login.js is a page inside page folder and the NavBar is a component inside components folder in the root.

```
import {
  Flex, Spacer, Box, Heading, Button,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { FC } from 'react';

interface NavBarProps {
  user: string | null;
  logout: () => void;
}

const NavBar: FC<NavBarProps> = ({ user, logout }: NavBarProps) => (
    <Flex bg="black" color="white" p="4">
      <Box p="2">
        <Heading size="md">
          <Link href="/">My Sanjow App</Link>
        </Heading>
      </Box>
      <Spacer />
      {user && (
        <Box pt="2" pr="4">
          <Heading size="md">
            <Link href="/users">Users</Link>
          </Heading>
        </Box>
      )}
      {user ? (
        <Button
          variant="ghost"
          pr="4"
          onClick={logout}
        >
          <Heading size="md">
            <Link href="/">Logout</Link>
          </Heading>
        </Button>
      ) : (
        <Box pt="2" pr="4">
          <Heading size="md">
            <Link href="/login">Login</Link>
          </Heading>
        </Box>
      )}
    </Flex>
);

export default NavBar;
```

The utils/localStorage/index

```
const lsType = {
  set: 'setItem',
  get: 'getItem',
  remove: 'removeItem',
};

const ls = (type: string, itemName: string, itemData?: string): void | string => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {

        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    const LS = window.localStorage;
    if (type === lsType.set && itemData) {
      LS[type](itemName, itemData);
      return;
    }
    return LS[type](itemName);
  }
};

export default {
  set(itemName: string, itemData: string): void {
    ls(lsType.set, itemName, itemData);
  },

  get(itemName: string): string {
    return ls(lsType.get, itemName) as string;
  },
  remove(itemName: string): void {
    ls(lsType.remove, itemName);
  },
};
```

Comment: maybe `window.localStorage` works?

Comment: useEffect do not run unless I refresh. It’s weird.

Comment: does it run during the first render? i mean when your NavBar component renders for the first time, put a console.log in the useEffect, and see whether it gets invoked

Comment: It does not console anything. Only after i refresh.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @juliomalves just provide the all code I think necessary. Anything you need further please ask. I would love some help... I can not figure this out...

Comment: Can you please show us what is inside the `utils/localStorage/index` ?

Comment: To clarify, is the problem that you're getting a "localStorage not defined" error inside `useEffect` OR that the `useEffect` is only running once?

Answer (score 0):

You are running the effect only once by passing the `[]` empty array, pass the  props that you expect to change instead of a blank array.

via the docs:

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and >unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This tells >React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always works.

Comment: I also used it with user inside the array in useEffect and it does not do anything…

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, managing `userInfo` only via `localStorage` is not a good idea, since you might want to re-render the application when user logs in or logs out, or any other change to the user data (i.e. change the username), and React is not subscribed to changes done to `localStorage`.

Instead, React has an instrument for runtime data management like that, it's called [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). That context (let's call it `UserContext`) could be initializing from `localStorage`, so that the case when you refresh the page for example. But after that initial bootstrapping all state management should go thru the context. Just don't forget to update both context and `localStorage` every time you login/logout.

I hope this is just enough to give you the right direction.

Comment: You are not answering his question though. You are suggesting completely different approach.

Comment: @CihangirBozdogan not really, I am answering what is needed to be added to make the approach of using `localStorage` work, in my opinion of course.